# Error using permission on custom User model

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

I am making a custom user model using `AbstractUser` in django.contrib.auth.models.

Everything was working fine until I wanted to make some changes in `user_permissions` of my `SiteUser` then Django gave an error that `SiteUser` has no attribute named `user_permissions`

Then I thought of extending `PermissionMixin` in django.contrib.auth.models to my `SiteUser` class to make changes in `user_permissions` but now It is throwing this error:

```
project.SiteUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'SiteUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'SiteUser.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'SiteUser.user_permissions' or 'SiteUser.user_permissions'.
project.SiteUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'SiteUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'SiteUser.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'SiteUser.user_permissions' or 'SiteUser.user_permissions'.
project.SiteUser.user_permissions: (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'project.SiteUser_user_permissions', which has not been installed.
```

P.S. - I have used `AUTH_USER_MODEL='project.CustomUser'`